# Meaning of "take over"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What's the meaning of *take over* in this context? Does it mean Mexico's population is becoming bigger than the US?

> P1: World population doubled in just 36 years, that is f-king unreal. The worst part is 
>   that the bulk of the reproducing population is 3rd world countries and the lower dregs 
>   of society (look at poor black families in Detroit vs successful middle class 
>   households).
>
> Do you think that we will end up destroying our own world? How long do you think this 
>   will take?
>
> P2: Mexicans are **taking over** the US. China and Japan will shrink. India is growing.

Comment: For questions like this, please always look things up in a dictionary beforehand. If the definitions do not help, state what it is that you find confusing. Wiktionary's entry for _take over_ can be found here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_over

Comment: The closest definition from OALD I thought was "to become bigger or more important than something else; to replace something", but I wasn't certain if that was the implication of the text.

Comment: I see. Please include such information in your questions in the future. It is often relevant :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a piece of racist nonsense. The writer expresses the opinion that increasing numbers of Mexicans in the US will obliterate the current population.

Comment: Might be a statement about illegal immigration also.

Answer (score 3):

It means "Mexicans are **taking control of** the US." And also one day there will be more Mexicans in US than native Americans. As a result of that, Mexicans will rule the country.

This is what my understanding is from the context as well as the literal meaning of the word.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're getting confused by two similar words. "Take over" means to take control of something. Like, "The German army will take over France." "Overtake" means to catch up with someone or something, like a person who is behind in a race passing another runner. "Fred took an early lead in the race, but Bob was able to overtake him and win."

As this is english.stackexchange and not politics.stackexchange, I shall exercise great restraint and not comment on the substance.

Comment: You have levels of self-control that are to be admired.

Answer (score 1):

This is the conventional meaning: [*take over* means “to take control of something”](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-over).

The implication in context is not that the population of *Mexico* is overtaking the population of the US, but that the US population of *Mexicans* (implied to be “lower dregs of society” who are “the bulk of the reproducing population”) is growing rapidly and that this trend will result in a Mexican takeover of the US.